# Spring Rspec binstub not improving speed with Rails 5 RC1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, spring-gem

I am using Rails 5 RC1. With the [spring-commands-rspec](https://github.com/jonleighton/spring-commands-rspec) gem (which hasn't been updated in a while at the time of writing), I have generated this spring rspec binstub in `bin/rspec`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
begin
  load File.expand_path('../spring', __FILE__)
rescue LoadError => e
  raise unless e.message.include?('spring')
end
require_relative '../config/boot'
load Gem.bin_path('rspec-core', 'rspec')
```

`bin/rspec` works, but if I run `bin/rspec` again, it takes as much time as the first time.

There is no speed improvement, even though `spring status` shows me this:

```
Spring is running:

29530 spring server | my_app | started 9 secs ago
29531 spring app    | my_app | started 9 secs ago | test mode
```

which suggests that everything is preloaded correctly.

The same setup works perfectly on Rails 4. Any idea on how to make it work in Rails 5 RC1?

Comment: Jerome, I'm assuming this isn't a relevant question any longer? If it is, have you tried bootspring? We've switched to that due to so many rails internal changes, a lot of the previous gems just weren't effective in improving boot time.

Comment: Do you have a link to this project? I can't find any gem with this name.

Comment: https://github.com/byroot/bootscale

Comment: Is there a reason you're sticking with RC1 still??

Comment: No I'm not on RC1, this question is quite old! But I am curious about bootscale, thanks for the tip

Comment: If it's actually helpful, I'll throw that in an answer, but this seems like a pretty niche case today. :)